# Control Sound and Vibration for Notifications in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-push-notification

I want to know if there's a way to control push notification's **sound** and **vibration** in a `react-native` project.

Actually I want to let user decide If notifications should have sound/vibration or not. User should be able to completely disable these functionalities.

I've search for this everywhere, but my question has differences with typical questions:

- I want to let user decide (If sound or vibration should be disabled or not), so I want some package or something that have `Javascript` implementation so that I could add this functionality to my app's setting view.
- I want to be able to do this in both IOS and Android.(feel free to answr if you have only knowledge in either case)

Answer (score 1):

as per documentation first you need to create channel

```
PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: "channel-id", // (required)
      channelName: "My channel", // (required)
      channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
      playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
      soundName: "default", // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
      importance: 4, // (optional) default: 4. Int value of the Android notification importance
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );
```

and use this channel id  "channel-id" in localnotification object

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
                channelId: "channel_id", 
                vibrate: true,
                title: "My Notification Title",
                message: "My Notification Message",
                onlyAlertOnce: false,
                ignoreInForeground: false,
                priority: "high",
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) package. just follow the documentation.

After installing the package and link it to the project.
Settings the notification is done (from documentation):

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    /* Android Only Properties */
    id: '0', // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
    ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // (optional)
    autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
    largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
    smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
    bigText: "My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded", // (optional) default: "message" prop
    subText: "This is a subText", // (optional) default: none
    color: "red", // (optional) default: system default
    vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
    vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
    tag: 'some_tag', // (optional) add tag to message
    group: "group", // (optional) add group to message
    ongoing: false, // (optional) set whether this is an "ongoing" notification
    priority: "high", // (optional) set notification priority, default: high
    visibility: "private", // (optional) set notification visibility, default: private
    importance: "high", // (optional) set notification importance, default: high

    /* iOS only properties */
    alertAction: // (optional) default: view
    category: // (optional) default: null
    userInfo: // (optional) default: null (object containing additional notification data)

    /* iOS and Android properties */
    title: "My Notification Title", // (optional)
    message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
    playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
    soundName: 'default', // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
    number: '10', // (optional) Valid 32 bit integer specified as string. default: none (Cannot be zero)
    repeatType: 'day', // (optional) Repeating interval. Check 'Repeating Notifications' section for more info.
    actions: '["Yes", "No"]',  // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
});
```

The package is for Android and iOS...one code for both platforms

few points to mention:

1. iOS - vibration & sound are combined, one can't disable the sound but activate the vibration
2. iOS - to enable only vibration without sound, you should "attach" a silent sound file that will be attached to the sound property.

Comment: Hello. Please does this work on expo? It seems the package is not for expo